# Pass data with segue form UITabBarItem not working

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, uitabbar

I want to pass data from one UIView to another UIView in order to go to the web site which will be different according to UITabBarItem that a user chooses. How can I do it?

```
func pathButton(dcPathButton: DCPathButton!, clickItemButtonAtIndex itemButtonIndex: UInt) {

    switch itemButtonIndex {

    case 0:

     // working but can’t send data with it
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto", sender: self) 

     // not working as function is not trigger
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "goto" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! WebMainViewController
            vc.goURL = "http://google.com“

        dcPathButton.delegate = self

        println(“go to http//google.com”)
        }
    case 1:
        println(“go to http://apple.com”)
    case 2:
        println(“go to http://imbd.com”)
    case 3:
        println(“go to http://facebook.com”)
    default:
        println(“go to http://cnn.com”)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
func pathButton(dcPathButton: DCPathButton!, clickItemButtonAtIndex itemButtonIndex: UInt) {
switch itemButtonIndex {
case 0:
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto", sender: self) 
   // plus other cases
}
```

and then in a different section of your class you implement:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "goto" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! WebMainViewController
        vc.goURL = "http://google.com“
}
```

Obviously *make sure that your segue is hooked up and has "goto" set as an identifier*.

Perhaps you could have some logic in `prepareForSegue` that sets `vc.goURL` instead of the switch statement that you currently have? For example, the user selects a particular value, you save that value to a variable and then when they click on a button to start the segue you check the value of that variable and set `vc.goURL` accordingly?